# runtime error in vba code

Tags: vba, runtime

My code is

```
    Sub PieMarkers()

Dim chtMarker As Chart
Dim chtMain As Chart
Dim intPoint As Integer
Dim rngRow As Range
Dim lngPointIndex As Long
Dim thmColor As Long
Dim myTheme As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set chtMarker = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtMarker").Chart
Set chtMain = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtMain").Chart

Set chtMain = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtMain").Chart
Set rngRow = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("PieChartValues").RefersTo)

For Each rngRow In Range("PieChartValues").Rows
    chtMarker.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngRow
    ThisWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load GetColorScheme(thmColor)
    chtMarker.Parent.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    lngPointIndex = lngPointIndex + 1
    chtMain.SeriesCollection(1).Points(lngPointIndex).Paste
    thmColor = thmColor + 1
Next

lngPointIndex = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetColorScheme(i As Long) As String
Const thmColor1 As String = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 15\Theme Colors\Blue Green.xml"
Const thmColor2 As String = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 15\Theme Colors\Orange Red.xml"
    Select Case i
        Case 0
            GetColorScheme = thmColor1
        Case 1
            GetColorScheme = thmColor2
    End Select
End Function
```

the code is meant to change the colour theme of successive pie charts which are used as bubbles in a bubble chart. So The function is just meant to select a colour scheme which I previously saved as a string and then to change it according to the run of the script so that the first pie has another colour than the next pie chart ....
I do get an error message when debugging the code at the line

```
 ThisWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load GetColorScheme(thmColor)
```

the error message is runtime error 2147024809 saying the indicated value is out of range..can anybody help me what appears to be the problem here?

Comment: I've provided the code to answer OP's orginal question which this is a duplicate of, and I am currently responding to queries about the error @Timon is experiencing. This error raises when the function `GetColorScheme` receives an `i` value that is not `0` or `1`. The function will return `False` which raises the error. I have provided some information on how to update this code for more than 2 cases, in the original thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments on the original thread...

[using VBA for a pie bubble chart in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347024/using-vba-for-a-pie-bubble-chart-in-excel/17348176#17348176)

**Cause of this Runtime Error**

There are two obvious things that might cause this error:

- The macro & function are currently set up to use only two color schemes, so if you try to call this function a third time or more, you will get this error. If you pass any `thmColor` index value that is not `0` or `1`, the function will return `False` instead of a valid string.
- The macro will also fail in any case where the returned string value is **not** a valid path & filename for an installed Theme on the user's machine. Double-check that you have supplied valid file path for the `thmColor1` and `thmColor2` variables inside the function.

The original answer has been updated to allow for rotating between the two specified color schemes. Use the `MOD` function in the `Select Case` statement, thusly:

```
Function GetColorScheme(i as Long) as String  '## Returns the path of a color scheme to load
    '## Currently set up to ROTATE between only two color schemes.
    '   You can add more, but you will also need to change the 
    '   Select Case i Mod 2, to i Mod n; where n = the number 
    '   of schemes you will rotate through.
    Const thmColor1 as String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14\Theme Colors\Apex.xml"
    Const thmColor2 as String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14\Theme Colors\Essential.xml"


    Select Case i Mod 2  '## i Mod n; where n = the number of Color Schemes.
        case 0
            GetColorScheme = thmColor1
        case 1
            GetColorScheme = thmColor2
        'Case n  '## You should have an additional case for each 1 to n.
        '
    End Select
End Function
```

For additional colors, you will need to initialize additional variables representing additional theme files, and modify the `Select Case` block accordingly.

You could go more complex than that, but without knowing exactly how many of these you need to apply, I provide a viable, scalable solution.  If you have very many charts and want to loop over the available themes, this could also be done. How complex the changes depends on how much variance you want, but you could conceivable declare an array and capture **ALL** installed themes in the themes folder, and just iterate over those sequentially.

Comment: Yeah, David you're spot on here, I missed the loop incrementing `thmColor` so once it hits `2` the function will return an empty string which if you run `ThisWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load ""` will give you the error. +1

Comment: @TimonHeinomann Please consider marking this as the **accepted** answer, and also marking my previous answer to the other question as accepted. That's how this site works, when others help you solve problems, :)  I will try to look at the other question later today.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a custom theme that you've created yourself (I haven't got 2013 installed but neither 2007 or 2010 have a Blue Green or Orange Red theme), I'd suggest that it is a problem with your XML file.

I believe that your `thmColor` variable will be initialised as a zero as numbers are in VBA and your code works fine for me if I substitute the path of your XML file for one of Microsoft's.  (Albeit always picking `thmColor1`.)

Furthermore, if I corrupt the XML in one of these files I get a error "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057) The file cannot be opened due to problems with the contents'.  Since you are getting the same error number with an out of range value I'm guessing you've got a colour incorrectly defined with a wrong hex value.